# Setting the contents of a CALayer to a CGImageRef on iOS with ARC on

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, calayer, automatic-ref-counting, cgimageref

The following code compiles fine with manual memory management, but fails under ARC:

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.contents = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"dial.png"] CGImage];
```

The error is:

> Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of a
>   non-Objective-C pointer type 'CGImageRef' (aka 'struct CGImage *') to
>   'id' is disallowed with ARC

How can I get this running with ARC?

Comment: I haven't used ARC but have you tried making it an *explicit* conversion, casting it to `(id)`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

CoreFoundation objets aren't managed by ARC. ARC only works with Objective-C objets and does not implicitly know how to transfer the ownership when casting from (or to) an non-object pointer type.

You need to tell ARC how the ownership of the objet is transferred during the cast:

```
layer.contents = (__bridge id) [[UIImage imageNamed:@"dial.png"] CGImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the result of `-CGImage` to a id, as it is complaining about implicit conversions...

```
layer.contents = (id) [[UIImage imageNamed:@"dial.png"] CGImage];
```

Comment: Hhmm, the compiler did stop bitching, but any idea why this is a no-no with ARC?

Comment: Because a `id` represents a `struct objc_object *`, where a `CGImageRef` represents a `struct CGImage *` (which is a `struct objc_object *` under the covers), which isn't a `struct objc_object *` the compiler cannot implicitly convert a non-object (especially one that is retained in the property) to an object.